# Would an object floating in a spinning cylinder in empty space be pushed toward the wall of the cylinder?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, rotation, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

This is a rather simple question, but it intrigues me nonetheless...
If there was a ball in a hollow cylinder that was spinning (on an axis) in empty space (no noticeable gravitational effects), and the ball was not in contact with the wall of the cylinder nor in motion relative to the cylinder before the spinning began, would it be attracted to the wall of the cylinder with a force proportional to the speed of rotation? Why or why not?

Comment: Why would you think that spinning the cylinder would have any effect on the ball if there is no contact?

Comment: I suppose I just imagined a ball sitting on a spinning disk, or a ball spinning on the end of a rope, and wondered if the same logic could be applied to such an example as the one I gave above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would not. The spinning has nothing to do with an attractive force.